# Dual Booted Laptop Win 7 & Ubuntu 14.04; Windows 10; Ubuntu choices?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-7

Have a newer Acer laptop which can accept Windows 10 installation. Laptop currently dual booted with Windows 7 Home Premium and Ubuntu 14.04 
Is it better to install Windows 10 and then use Boot Repair to fix any problems with already installed Ubuntu 14.04 OR should I uninstall and reinstall Ubuntu after I have installed Windows 10? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you have good backups. Is system UEFI or BIOS? Most Windows 7 were BIOS but some newer hardware was UEFI even with a BIOS install. If BIOS, best to have both Windows installs in primary partitions. And create NTFS partition and move boot flag to it before install. Otherwise second Windows install puts all its boot files in first Windows install and overwrites first installs boot files. More difficult to undo if you later want just one Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can do either order, but what matters is making sure you don't wipe another install to install an OS.  I would do Win10 then boot repair if it were me.